# Shared directory for file upload across subdomains on linux

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, file-upload, subdomain

I have a 2 modules that must share common directory for a specific uploaded files.

instructor.example.com
And
registrar.example.com

So what I want to know ,is what you guys do to make them have a common directory for the file uploads and where is it directory placed?

Because users from registrar.example.com must able to access the directory of the instructor users , specific directory of uploaded files.

For example name it "instructor_registrar/{instructor-id}/ cause I have OCD.

I already have made my research and I found 1 who has similar problem like mine but they just said "you can put it anywhere". So I want to know where should I create the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with an alternative.
Here's what I did. I have 2 framework in 1 subdomain.

```
/var/www/staff.example.com/instructor/
/var/www/staff.example.com/registrar/
```

I created another directory inside:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/staff.example.com/uploads/shared_dir/
```

and set the privacy to 755

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/staff.example.com/uploads/shared_dir/
```

and also set the owner to root

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/staff.example.com/uploads/shared_dir/
and set my `$upload_path` on file upload model to

```
$uploadpath = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/shared_dir/';
```

because I need to create a personal directory if the user is new. I set all files inside /var/www/ owned by apache and all groups and users and enable read and write files for all members of www-data group to enable to make my `mkdir()` before uploading the file.

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/shared_dir/'.$_SESSION['user_id'], 0777, true);
```

(*I don't recommend it but this is what I did*)

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

That settles my file uploading outside the root or framework.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with linux directory / file permissions.

Let's say:

- Site 1: runs under user `siteuser1` and group `sitegroup1`.  All directories and files for that specific site are owned by `siteuser1` and `sitegroup1`.
- Site 2: runs under user `siteuser2` and group `sitegroup2`.  All directories and files for that specific site are owned by `siteuser2` and `sitegroup2`.

For your shared directory and files, set it up like this:

- /shared_dir/fileA, fileB, fileC, ...
- The directory should be owned by `someuser` and `somegroup`.
- Put users `siteuser1` and `siteuser2` in `somegroup`
- Put the permissions like this:

  ```
  drwxr-x--- someuser somegroup /shared_dir/
  -rw-r----- someuser somegroup /shared_dir/fileA
  -rw-r----- someuser somegroup /shared_dir/fileB
  ...
  ```

This way all users in group `somegroup` have access to the files.

You could put the `others` permissions to r--, but I do not like giving read permissions to every user on a directory or fles.

---

EDIT:

For the location of the shared directory, anywhere outside the site specific directories is fine.  And do not forget to declare it in your Apache configuration with a `<Directory ...>` section.

Lets say your web sites files are under `/opt/apache/htdocs_instructor` and `/opt/apache/htdocs_registrar`, you could do `/opt/apache/htdocs_shared`

Comment: Thank you. I just decided not to create an another user but , just assigned the instructor as root same as with the registrars. I know there are disadvantages about this, but thank you for helping me.